# Android obfuscate app using proguard keeps jar libs

Tags: java, android, jar, proguard

I want to create simple example of using proguard.
in my example i have apfloat.jar lib in libs folder and onclick listener in xml.

```
public void f1(View item) {

    if (item.getId() == R.id.button1) {

        Apfloat x = new Apfloat("100");
        x = x.add(new Apfloat("10"));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked "+x.toString(true).toString(), 5).show();

    }

}
```

when i use proguard with this configuration

```
# This is a configuration file for ProGuard.
# http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#manual/usage.html

-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose

# Optimization is turned off by default. Dex does not like code run
# through the ProGuard optimize and preverify steps (and performs some
# of these optimizations on its own).
#-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify

# If you want to enable optimization, you should include the
# following:
# -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
# -optimizationpasses 5
# -allowaccessmodification
#
# Note that you cannot just include these flags in your own
# configuration file; if you are including this file, optimization
# will be turned off. You'll need to either edit this file, or
# duplicate the contents of this file and remove the include of this
# file from your project's proguard.config path property.

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgent
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class * extends android.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

# For native methods, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#native
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
}

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
public <init>(android.content.Context);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

#-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
 #  public void *(android.view.View);
#}

# For enumeration classes, see http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#enumerations
-keepclassmembers enum * {
public static **[] values();
public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

# The support library contains references to newer platform versions.
# Don't warn about those in case this app is linking against an older
# platform version.  We know about them, and they are safe.
-dontwarn android.support.**

#-dontwarn apfloat.jar.**




 -keep class apfloat.** { *; }



-keepclassmembers class * {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```

i got this error messages

```
 Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find superclass or interface org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find superclass or interface org.jscience.mathematics.structure.Field
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.MemoryUsage
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.MemoryUsage
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.MemoryMXBean
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.ApfloatContext: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.MemoryUsage
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class javolution.text.Text
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.structure.Field
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class javolution.text.Text
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class javolution.text.Text
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AbstractField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.structure.Field
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ApcomplexField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ApfloatField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.AprationalField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.FixedPrecisionApcomplexField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.FixedPrecisionApfloatField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext$Reference
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext$Reference
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext$Reference
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext$Reference
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext$Reference
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class javolution.context.LocalContext$Reference
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: org.apfloat.jscience.ModuloApintField: can't find referenced class org.jscience.mathematics.number.Number
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] Warning: there were 33 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard]    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2014-09-28 08:38:26 - proguard]    at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

i know i can avoid this error message whit using

```
-dontwarn org.jscience.**
-dontwarn org.apfloat.**
```

when i use this codes my example export fine but when i lunched in phone and i click on button my app crash.
so how can i fix this? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

at last i found my answer.

```
-dontwarn org.jscience.**
-dontwarn org.apfloat.**

-keep class apfloat.** { *; }
-keep class org.jscience.** { *; }
-keep class org.apfloat.** { *; }
```

Comment: Mark your answer as solution as soon as possible. :)